How to speed up this code? (related to list manipulation)
This code is a program for generating a 2D roughness surface. There is no problem when the image size (m * n) is small (e.g., 50 * 50), but when it gets larger (e.g., 500 * 500), errors occur and the process fails. It seems that the required memory becomes enormous when the image size is large.
Could you modify this code to generate a large image without errors?
Thank you for your advice.
m = 100;(*image size*)
n = 100;(*image size*)
sig = 1.2; (*roughness parameter1*)
bx = 10;   (*roughness parameter2*)
by = 20;   (*roughness parameter3*)

rbxby[x_,y_]=sig^2 Exp[-2.3((x/bx)^2+(y/by)^2)^0.5];
lgr=ParallelTable[rbxby[x,y],{x,0,m-1},{y,0,n-1}];

sqlgs=
ParallelTable[Sqrt[Sum[lgr[[r+1,s+1]]*Exp[-2 I Pi (k r/m+l s/n)],{r,0,m-1},{s,0,n-1}]/(m n)],
{k,0,m-1},{l,0,n-1}];

phi=ParallelTable[Table[RandomReal[{0,2 Pi}],{n}],{m}];
phi=ParallelTable[If[(k<=m/2)&&k!=0&&l!=0,-phi[[m-k+1,n-l+1]],phi[[k+1,l+1]]],{k,0,m-1},{l,0,n-1}];
phi = ParallelTable[If[(l<=n/2)&&k!=0&&l!=0,-phi[[m-k+1,n-l+1]],phi[[k+1,l+1]]],{k,0,m-1},{l,0,n-1}];
For[k=0+1,k<=m/2,k++,phi[[k+1,0+1]]=-phi[[m-k+1,0+1]]];
For[l=0+1,l<=n/2,l++,phi[[0+1,l+1]]=-phi[[0+1,n-l+1]]];
phi[[0+1,0+1]]=phi[[0+1,n/2+1]]=phi[[m/2+1,0+1]]=phi[[m/2+1,n/2+1]]=0;

kpmlqn=ParallelTable[Table[k p/m+l q/n,{k,0,m-1},{l,0,n-1}],{p,0,m-1},{q,0,n-1}];

zpq=ParallelTable[Total[Flatten[sqlgs Exp[I 2 Pi (phi+kpmlqn[[p+1,q+1]])]]],{p,0,m-1},{q,0,n-1}];
zpq=ParallelTable[If[Im[zpq[[p+1,q+1]]]<0.001,zpq[[p+1,q+1]]=Re[zpq[[p+1,q+1]]]],{p,0,m-1},{q,0,n-1}]));

zpqnum0=ParallelTable[Riffle[Table[{j,i},{i,0,n-1}],zpq[[j+1]]],{j,0,m-1}];
zpqnum1=Partition[Flatten[zpqnum0],3]; (*Output*)

(*Plot*)
ListPlot3D[zpqnum1,
 Boxed -> False,
 PlotRange -> All,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic,
 Axes -> {True, True, False},
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 AxesStyle -> {Directive[Black, 16, Thick],Directive[Black, 16, Thick], None},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, Thick],
 Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"(*"SouthwestColors"*)]


Additional information:
This code becomes much faster than the original one by following modifications.
sqlgs = Sqrt[Fourier[lgr, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]/(m n)]
kpmlqn -> delete
add -> shiftedfourier = sqlgs Exp[2 Pi I phi]
zpq = InverseFourier[shiftedfourier, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}]
With this modification, images with a size of 2500*2500 can be computed in a realistic time (34 seconds on my PC).
However, images larger than that (e.g., 3000*3000) fail due to other problems. Here is examples of the error outputs:

(kernel 1) General::stop :  Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.


(kernel 1) General::munfl :  Exp[-708.467] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Hm. You have several 4-fold loops, this gives the algorithm a complexity of $O(m^2 n^2)$. You have many expressions like Exp[I 2 Pi (k p/m + l q/n)]. Something tells me that you should be able to use fast Fourier transform to reduce the complexity to $O(m \log(m) , n \log(n))$. But since I don't really understand what you are doing there, I cannot tell how exactly you should do it. Long story short: You have to tune your algorithm, not its implementation.

Thank you. Fast Fourier transform speeded up the calculation. However, another problem arises and it fails for image sizes of 3000*3000. Could you check the edits I have made?

This underflow is quite typical for Exp. As the message says, Exp is fed the number -708.467 and the result cannot be represented by double precision floating point numbers. Most likely this happens in rbxby. For most computations, these small numbers are effectively 0.. So it should be save for truncate the inputs to Exp Simply truncate the inputs to Exp to -709. or higher.

Btw.: Great that you worked it out with FFT!

Thank you very much. In typical situations, Exp in rbxby is almost zero when the image size is greater than 1000, so if we truncate it at 1000, the calculation is done without error.
